# Cypress Test to login with keycloak Free OTP or Google Authenticator

Tags: javascript, authentication, cypress, keycloak, totp

as per my understanding we can test the login of user in cypress with OTP by using the package below.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-keycloak. To successfully login I need otp_secret and otp_credential_id below

```
 cy.loginOTP({
      root: 'https://keycloak.com',
      realm: 'test',
      username: 'test',
      password: 'test',
      client_id: '1234567',
      redirect_uri: 'https://redirecturl.com/',
      otp_secret: 'OZLDC2HZKM3QUC...', // e.g. 32 chars
      otp_credential_id: '5e231f20-8ca7-35e1-20a694b60181ca9', // e.g. 36 chars
    });
  });
```

When I make a call to keycloak endpoint GET /{realmName}/users/{userId}/credentials

I can only see the credentials id and not the secret. Here is my sample response

```
[
    {
        "id": "123456789999",
        "type": "otp",
        "createdDate": 1657189911231,
        "credentialData": "{\"subType\":\"totp\",\"digits\":6,\"counter\":0,\"period\":30,\"algorithm\":\"HmacSHA1\"}"
    }
]
```

Can someone please advise how to fetch the client secret? or if there is any other way to test OTP

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps.

before scanning the QR code on your mobile just take a screenshot of it and upload it on https://zxing.org this will decode and return you the otp secret id.

The API GET /{realmName}/users/{userId}/credentials

returned me otp-credential-id and extracted secret from zxing, now I am able to authenticate and run my cypress tests.